# Writing a number on a plot with a decimal digit

Tags: r, text, plot, digits

I have for example a vector like that:

```
time <- c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)
```

If I have to write the third element in a graph I have to use this command:

```
text(7.5,75, time[3])
```

It appears as a 1, but I want it as 1.0, how can I make the first decimal digits appear?

Comment: Indexing in R starts with 1, not with 0. Also, you can use `sprintf` for formating the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sprintf("%.1f", time)` you wil set the decimal digits to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach that wraps `sprintf`.  It's one I keep around for reports.  Note it also removes non significant leading zeros.

```
numfor <- function (val, digits, override = FALSE) {

    if (all(is.Integer(val), na.rm = TRUE) & !override) {
        sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf(paste0("%.0f"), val))
    } else {
        sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf(paste0("%.", digits, "f"), val))
    }
}

is.Integer <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  {
    abs(x - round(x)) < tol
}

time <- c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)
numfor(time, 1)

## [1] ".0"  ".5"  "1.0" "1.5" "2.0" "2.5"
```

And what `override` does:

```
## > numfor(1:10, 1)
##  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

## > numfor(1:10, 1, override=TRUE)
##  [1] "1.0"  "2.0"  "3.0"  "4.0"  "5.0"  "6.0"  "7.0"  "8.0"  "9.0"  "10.0"
```

Comment: thank you. I tried but I probably did something wrong, i solved the problem anyway.